# Is it appropriate to use it?

Tags: complex-sentences

Is it appropriate to say this sentence please?

My mother wanted me to grow up to be a princess

Thank you all!

Comment: Why do you think anything could be wrong with it? What exactly is your difficulty? What do you mean by 'appropriate' -- grammar, politeness, or something else? Please expand your question to explain. Do it fast or it may get closed :)

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically correct (aside from the missing period at the end of the sentence.) As to whether it is appropriate, I think that is more a question for [parenting portal.](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: We do not know what exactly is the OP's question, or his problem with its grammar.